# Global verification function in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can we put global verification function in JMeter script as like in load runner

web_global_verification("Text/IC=ERROR",
        "Fail=Found",
        "Search=Body",
        LAST);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]

So if there will be `error` text (case insensitive) in any of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) that Sampler will be marked as failed

[image]

JMeter Assertions obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) therefore you need to either place it at the same level as the Samplers you would like to check or a level higher. If you make the assertion a child of the Sampler - it will be applied to that sampler only.